# beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications is not called

Tags: swift, apple-music, apple-musickit

beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications doesn't seem to be being called in my app. I can fetch the storeIds and the music is playing (and I can skip forwards and backwards) but the notification never seems to be called. Any advice or is there something I'm missing?

```
        let player = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationQueuePlayer

        // Trying all of these
        player.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
        MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
        MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
        MPMusicPlayerController.applicationQueuePlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(refreshView),
                                               name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange,
                                               object: self)


        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(refreshView),
                                               name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange,
                                               object: self)

    let queue  = MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor(storeIDs: storeIds)
    player.setQueue(with: queue)
    player.play()

    // Never called
    @objc func refreshView(){
      let nowPlaying = player.nowPlayingItem
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines are wrong:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(refreshView),
                                           name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange,
                                           object: self)


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(refreshView),
                                           name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange,
                                           object: self)
```

Change

```
  object: self
```

To

```
  object: nil
```

In both.